# Passing a sql backup file through the docker daemon to populate a docker database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

#### Context

I need to populate a database inside a docker container from a backup file that I have on the host machine.

I've tried this `docker` command while the PostGIS container is up (see `docker-compose.yml` at the end):

```
sudo docker exec -i db_container_1 ./usr/local/bin/pg_restore --no-owner --role=postgres -h localhost -U postgres -p 5434 -d database_name < ../db/dumps/dump_prod_2020.backup
```

But I've got this message:

```
read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
```

As documented [here](https://gist.github.com/jgillman/8191d6f587ffc7207a88e987e034b675), I also tried using this `docker-compose` command but it raises the exact same strange message:

```
docker-compose exec -T db /usr/local/bin/pg_restore --no-owner --role=postgres -h localhost -U postgres -p 5434 -d database_name < ../db/dumps/dump_prod_2020.backup
```

#### Question

What am I doing wrong and how could I populate my docker database with my local dump?

#### More infos

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` used to start the db service (`docker ps` outputs `db_container_1` as the corresponding container name):

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  db_data:

services:

  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:11-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: database_name
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT:-5434}:5432'
    restart: 'no'
    volumes:
      - './docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro'
      - 'db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data' # to persist storage
```

Comment: Can you run `pg_restore` from the host, connecting to the published port (`-h localhost -p 5434`), without using `docker exec`?  If you're using `sudo docker exec` here, the `pg_restore` command runs inside the container, and it will see the normal PostgreSQL port 5432 and not know about the `ports:` remapping.

Comment: Yes I can, indeed, but the problem is that my local pg is older. I already tried and I noticed I had troubles and errors while importing the dump the way you described because of version incompatibilities; the pg version inside docker is higher (and corresponds to the the version of the production server, from where the dump originally comes from). That's why I would like to be able to run it from inside the docker container. I don't want to do a fancy-upgrade of my local pg (which is the official package shipped by `apt` on my local Ubuntu desktop).